# Confusion about S-R and J-K FF

Tags: flipflop

I've designed S-R and J-K Flip Flops, their truth tables as I searched on the web, examined all of results on it and wrote as in the picture. Because of designing alternatives, I am confused and not sure about it at the moment. For example, when I search S-R or J-K Flip Flops, Google shows me lots of truth tables and designing which are different with mine. Can you please check whether this is correct or not? If it is not correct, what kind of changing must be done?

"Tanımsız which has been written for Q=0, Q'=1 means undefined/invalid."
[image]

Comment: A SR latch has no required output for S-1,R=1, as this state is not allowed.

Comment: @Scott Seidman I had explained that "tanımsız" which writes for R=1 and S=1 means "invalid". However, it hadn't been appeared. Sorry for this. I indicated again.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: In many cases, it can be useful for an SR latch to define behavior for all combinations of inputs *except* the simultaneous deactivation of R and S.  A typical behavioral spec would have Q and /Q both high, or both low.

Answer (score 1):

The two circuits shown are not flip-flops. They are gated-latches. Flip-flops are always edge triggered. The web is full of mistakes as related to flip-flops.

The truth tables are correct for the circuits you have shown, except for the very last state for the "J-K" circuit.

The very concept of a J-K gated-latch like the one shown is flawed. When "Clk", "J" and "K" are active, that circuit is unstable. The outputs are not predictable in that state.

Comment: Thanks, I've really enlightened. I had done a mistake as you said when I thought about last state for J-K gated-latch. Therefore, I drawed the circuit, examined it again and extrapolated that Q and Q' must be low when all the inputs (J-K and Clk) are high. Because, if we handle J,K and Clk are high, the outputs of and gates will be Q for the first one and Q' for the second one. If we continue in this state for the nor gates, for example first one; the inputs will be (Q + Q')' and for the second nor gate; the inputs will be (Q + Q)' and this gives us 0 for Q and Q'. Am I wrong?

Comment: One way to look at this is when J, K and Clk are high, then Q1 = Q1' + Q2'; Q2 = Q1' + Q2' (Q1 is the top output, Q2 is the bottom). Since the two equations are the same, we look for a stable solution where Q1 = Q2. Fit in Q1=Q2=1, or Q1=Q2=0, both are invalid. There is no stable state. In a real circuit, most likely to happen is the outputs wiggle around the input threshold voltage.